# Integrate Postman with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, postman

I would like to know if there is a way to integrate Postman with SQL Server Management Studio. This is required for API server side testing purposes.

My intention is to insert data using Postman JSON scripts and connect to SQL Server database and verify that the data is available in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Postman's a UI for executing web requests; SQL Server Management Studio is a UI for managing databases. If you want to insert data into a SQL Server database with Postman, you'll need a web API in the middle that can interpret your JSON requests and insert database records; then you can use SQL Server Management Studio to query the database tables.

Comment: Hi Max. My question was more about, if there is a HTTP plugin for SQL Server management studio which i can use and connect to it through postman, run the select queries in postman and verify the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Apache Drill which is open source.
https://drill.apache.org/docs/use-postman-to-run-sql-queries-on-drill-data-sources/
https://medium.com/@annieasad171994/postman-to-run-sql-queries-225da21fd2